# How to get multiple users in wordpress by id

Tags: wordpress

what should be the best way to find names for multiple users in wordpress by using user ids? 
e.g. I can find the info by following:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name FROM wp_users WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)")
```

But is there any better way in wordpress? 
don't want to use loops to avoid performance problems.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

but it will do almost the same like your code.

There is a fields parameter that you can use to get the field that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), which is a wrapper for WP_User_Query.